# RegisterForRemoteNotifications throws com.apple.UNSNotificationRegistrarConnection

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications

The app called the following methods to register push notification when the app launched

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerUserNotificationSettings:[UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:(UIUserNotificationTypeBadge | UIUserNotificationTypeSound | UIUserNotificationTypeAlert) categories:nil]];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotifications];
```

However there is a small chance that the app will throw the following exception when it executes registerForRemoteNotifications

> Crashed: com.apple.UNSNotificationRegistrarConnection
>   EXC_BAD_ACCESS KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS

It is difficult to reproduce and not always happens. Does anyone know what is the root cause of this issue? Many thanks.